# FTP and python question

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Can someone help me.

Why it is not working

```
import ftplib
import os

def readList(request):
         machine=[]
         login=[]
         password=[]
         for line in open("netrc"): #read netrc file
            old=line.strip()
            line=line.strip().split()
            if old.startswith("machine"): machine.append(line[-1])
            if old.startswith("login"): login.append(line[-1])
            if old.startswith("password"): password.append(line[-1])
            connectFtp(machine,login,password)

def connectFtp(machine,login,password):
  for i in range(len(machine)):
          try:
             ftp = ftplib.FTP(machine[i])
             print 'conected to ' + machine[i]
             ftp.login(login[i],password[i])
             print 'login - ' + login[i] + ' pasword -' + password[i]
           except Exception,e:
             print e
           else:
       ftp.cwd("PublicFolder")
    print 'PublicFolder'

def upload(filename, file):
       readList()
          ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
            if ext in (".txt", ".htm", ".html"):
            ftp.storlines("STOR " + filename, open(file))
            else:
             ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, open(file, "rb"), 1024)
             print 'success... yra'

upload('test4.txt', r'c:\example2\media\uploads\test4.txt')`
```

When it was together it was working. But when i separate it in to functions something happened, I cant understand what.

Comment: your indentations are wrong for once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Apart from the horrid indentation problems, which are presumably due to botched copy and paste otherwise you'd get syntax errors up the wazoo...!)...:

Scoping problem, first: `connectFtp` makes a **local** variable `ftp` so that variables goes away as soon as the function's done.  Then `upload` tries using the variable, but of course it isn't there any more.

Add a `return ftp` at the end of `connectFtp`, a `yield connectFtp` instead of a plain call to the loop in `readList`, and use a `for ftp in readList():` loop in `upload`.

Comment: What do you mean instead of plan call?

Comment: @user, I mean the `connectFtp(machine,login,password)` you used to have -- just a call, **plain**, not **plan** (editing to fix typo), to be replaced with `yield connectFtp(machine,login,password)` (as well as the other changes I suggested _and_ indentation fixes too of course;-).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import os


def readList(request):
    machine = []
    login = []
    password = []
    for line in open("netrc"):  # read netrc file
        old = line.strip()
        line = line.strip().split()
        if old.startswith("machine"): machine.append(line[-1])
        if old.startswith("login"): login.append(line[-1])
        if old.startswith("password"): password.append(line[-1])
        yield connectFtp


def connectFtp(machine, login, password):
    for i in range(len(machine)):


try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(machine[i])
    print 'conected to ' + machine[i]
    ftp.login(login[i], password[i])
    print 'login - ' + login[i] + ' pasword -' + password[i]
except Exception, e:
    print e
else:
    ftp.cwd("PublicFolder")
    print 'PublicFolder'
    return (ftp)


def upload(filename, file):
    for ftp in readList():
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if ext in (".txt", ".htm", ".html"):
        ftp.storlines("STOR " + filename, open(file))
    else:
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, open(file, "rb"), 1024)
    print 'success... yra'

upload('test4.txt', r'c:\example2\media\uploads\test4.txt')
```

Error at line 19 something with `try:`
unindent does not math any outer indentation level